# Sub-coroot lattices

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

[This is a sequel to the previous question [sub-coroot systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441161/sub-coroot-systems), that has been answered! :-) ]

Let $T$ be a maximal torus of a compact Lie group $K$,
and let $\Lambda \subset {\mathfrak t}$ be the coroot lattice for $(K,T)$, where $\mathfrak t$ is the Lie algebra of $T$.

Assume now that $K'$ is another compact Lie group that admits a homomorphic embedding $i:K\hookrightarrow K'$ verifying the condition that $i(Z_K)\subset Z_{K'}$, where $Z_K, Z_{K'}$ are the centers of $K$ and $K'$, respectively. Let $T'$ be a maximal torus of $K'$ such that $i(T)\subset T'$. This gives a vector space inclusion ${\mathfrak t} \subset {\mathfrak t}'$, into the Lie algebra of $T'$.

Question: Is it true that
$$ \Lambda = {\mathfrak t} \cap \Lambda'$$

where $\Lambda' \subset {\mathfrak t}'$ is the coroot lattice of $(K',T')$?

If this is not always true, are there some simple conditions under which it becomes true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441161/sub-coroot-systems), I will work with complex Lie groups, but you can pass to maximal compact subgroups if you prefer.

Consider the natural embedding $\operatorname{SO}_4(\mathbb C) \to \operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb C)$, where $\operatorname{SO}_4$ is taken with respect to the quadratic form $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \mapsto x_1 x_4 + x_2 x_3$.  If we denote the simple (with respect to the upper-triangular Borel) roots of the diagonal torus in $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb C)$ by $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$, in the obvious fashion, then the common restriction of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ to the diagonal torus in $\operatorname{SO}_4(\mathbb C)$ is a simple (with respect to the upper-triangular Borel) root $a$, and the common restriction of $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_2 + \alpha_3$ is a simple root $b$.  Then $a^\vee$ equals $\alpha_1^\vee + \alpha_3^\vee$, $b^\vee$ equals $\alpha_1^\vee + 2\alpha_2^\vee + \alpha_3^\vee$, and $\Lambda$ equals $\mathbb Z a^\vee + \mathbb Z b^\vee$, but $(\Lambda' \cap \mathfrak t)/\Lambda$ has order $2$, generated by the image of $\alpha_2^\vee$.

Comment: Thank you again, @LSpice! Decidedly, these are subtle questions. 
Are there any conditions that guarantee equality, in terms for example, of the fundamental groups of $K$, $K'$, or the cardinals of the centers?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138138_441185), in both of my examples, $K_{\mathbb C}$ is the identity component of the fixed-point group of a so-called quasi-semisimple automorphism of $K'_{\mathbb C}$ (one that stabilises both a Borel, in my case the upper-triangular Borel, and a maximal torus in that Borel, in my case the diagonal torus).  From that point of view, what's going wrong in this case is the failure of the automorphism to preserve a pinning. […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1138141)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138139_441185) Even for a pinned automorphism, you run into trouble when your root system has a component of type $\mathsf A_{2n}$ on which your automorphism acts non-trivially.  (That is, $\operatorname{SO}_5 \subseteq \operatorname{SL}_5$ exhibits the same bad behaviour I've described here.)  Otherwise, for fixed points of pinned automorphisms, everything is fine; but I'm not sure if that special case is general enough to be of interest to you.

Comment: This [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138139_441185) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138141_441185) is described in [Adler and Lansky - Root data with group actions](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-13-6628-4_3), though related discussions have appeared elsewhere, e.g., in papers of Digne and Michel, such as, if I remember correctly, [Quasi-semisimple elements](https://doi-org.ezproxy.tcu.edu/10.1112/plms.12121).

Comment: In terms [specifically](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138138_441185) of the fundamental group, if $K$ is simply connected, then $\Lambda$ is the natural integral form $X_*(T) = \operatorname{Hom}(X^*(T), \mathbb Z)$ of $\operatorname{Hom}(X^*(T), \mathbb C) = \mathfrak t_{\mathbb C}$, so at least $\Lambda' \cap \mathfrak t$ is contained in $\Lambda$ (in general, without any assumptions on how $K$ and $K'$ arise); and, if $K'$ is simply connected, then we in fact have equality.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices#comment1138151_441185), I should have said more generally that, if $K'$ is simply connected (whether or not $K$ is), then $\Lambda' \cap \mathfrak t$ contains $\Lambda$ (again, without any assumptions on how $K$ and $K'$ arise).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices/441185#comment1138142_441185), sorry, that second paper link is behind a proxy.  It should be [Digne and Michel - Quasi-semisimple elements](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms.12121).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments @LSpice! I believe that in all your examples the following holds: The intersection of a Weyl chamber for $\Lambda '$ with $\mathfrak t$ equals precisely a Weyl chamber for $\Lambda$. Does this hold in general, say for $K$ and $K'$ semisimple, with the given assumptions on the inclusion? I could post this as a new question, but I can wait.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1138289), strictly speaking one should speak of a chamber for the root system in $\mathfrak t$ (or for the coroot system in $\mathfrak t^*$).  Write $\Phi$ for roots.  That $Z_K$ is carried into $Z_{K'}$ means that the image in $X^*(T)$ of the annihilator $\mathbb Z\Phi'$ of $Z_{K'}$ in $X^*(T)$ is contained in the annihilator $\mathbb Z\Phi$ of $Z_K$ in $X^*(T')$.  If $Z_K$ has finite index in $Z_{K'} \cap T$, then the image of $\mathbb Q\Phi$ equals $\mathbb Q\Phi'$, so $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ determine the same chamber decomposition of $\mathfrak t$.

Comment: So [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices/441185#comment1138329_441185) handles the case where $K'$ is semisimple.  Without assuming that $K'$ is semisimple, if $K$ is semisimple, then the image of $K$ in $K'$ lands in the derived group of the latter, which is semisimple, so we may compute Weyl chambers there.  (I assume you have meant all along for your groups to be connected, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks again, @LSpice. I believe that under the projection between character lattices, call it $\pi$, we have: $\mathbb{Z}\Phi'\subset X^{*}(T')\overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow}X^{*}(T) \supset \mathbb{Z}\Phi$. So, above you meant "the annihilator $\mathbb{Z}\Phi$ of $Z_K$ in $X^*(T)$.", instead of "... in $X^*(T')$.", right?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441180/sub-coroot-lattices/441185#comment1138723_441185), yes, sorry.  I am used to using unprimed letters for groups and primed letters for subgroups, so I had to fight with my instincts while writing this, and it looks like the fight was not successful.